# My code giving differnt result where as the same code in my Machine learning assignment expects a different result?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression

**MY CODE**

```
def lrCostFunction(theta, X, y, lambda_):
    m = y.size

    if y.dtype == bool:
        y = y.astype(int)

    tempt = theta
    tempt[0] = 0

    J = 0
    grad = np.zeros(theta.shape)
    hx = X.dot(theta.T)
    h = sigmoid(hx)

    J = (1/m) * np.sum(-y.dot(np.log(h)) - (1-y).dot(np.log(1-h)))
    J = J + (lambda_/(2*m)) * np.sum(np.square(tempt))

    grad = ((1/m) * (h - y) .dot(X)) + (lambda_/m) * tempt

    return J, grad

# rand_indices = np.random.choice(m, 100, replace=False)
# sel = X[rand_indices, :]\


theta_t = np.array([-2, -1, 1, 2], dtype=float)
X_t = np.concatenate([np.ones((5, 1)), np.arange(1, 16).reshape(5, 3, order='F')/10.0], axis=1)
y_t = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
lambda_t = 3

cost, gradient = lrCostFunction(theta_t, X_t, y_t, lambda_t)
print("J= ", cost, "\nGrad= ", gradient)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
J=  3.0857279966152817 
Grad=  [ 0.35537648 -0.49170896  0.88597928  1.66366752]
```

where as the assignment asks for these results from the same input:

```
print('Cost         : {:.6f}'.format(J))
print('Expected cost: 2.534819')
print('-----------------------')
print('Gradients:')
print(' [{:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}]'.format(*grad))
print('Expected gradients:')
print(' [0.146561, -0.548558, 0.724722, 1.398003]');
```

I even searched the internet for answers everyone had the same code as me and they stated that their result is same as predicted. I went to as far as copying their code on my pycharm IDE but i got the same answer again.
**The inputs are same too if u wanna  read the question its "Vectorizing regularized logistic regression"**

Link: [PYTHON ASSIGNMENT OF ANDREW NG ML COURSE](https://github.com/dibgerge/ml-coursera-python-assignments/blob/master/Exercise3/exercise3.ipynb)

**LINK TO ONE OF THE GUYS SOLUTION THAT HAS SAME CODE AND RIGHT ANSWER:**

LINK: [ONE OF THE GUYS CLAIMING TO HAVE THE EXPECTED RESULT FROM SAME CODE AS MINE](https://github.com/Akpandita/Andrew-NG-ML-Python-Solutions/blob/master/Exercise3/exercise3.ipynb)

This happened to me on one part of the last assignment as well, its really frustrating so i am reaching out for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. The problem is that when you change the value `tempt[0]` you are also changing `theta[0]`. Doing a copy of `theta` ensures that the initial vector is not changed.

```
def lrCostFunction(theta, X, y, lambda_):
    m = y.size

    if y.dtype == bool:
        y = y.astype(float)
    
    J = 0
    grad = np.zeros(theta.shape)
    hx = X.dot(theta.T)
    h = sigmoid(hx)

    tempt = np.copy(theta)    # Copy of theta
    tempt[0] = 0
    
    J = (1/m) * np.sum(-y.dot(np.log(h)) - (1-y).dot(np.log(1-h)))
    J = J + (lambda_/(2*m)) * np.sum(np.square(tempt))
    
    grad = ((1/m) * (h - y) .dot(X)) + (lambda_/m) * tempt
    
    print(theta, tempt)
    return J, grad

cost, gradient = lrCostFunction(theta_t, X_t, y_t, lambda_t)
print("J= ", cost, "\nGrad= ", gradient)

# Output:
# [-2. -1.  1.  2.] [ 0. -1.  1.  2.]
# J=  2.534819396109744 
# Grad=  [ 0.14656137 -0.54855841  0.72472227  1.39800296]
```